# Embedding Collection of Forms: check if entity exists

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-forms

I am implementing [this tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html). However in my case `Tag` entity has a unique `name` property:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=63, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Task", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tasks_tags")
     */
    protected $tasks;

  }
```

How can I check if `Tag` entity already exists, in `new` and `edit` controllers, so that I can decide to create new one. If `Tag` exists, I can add it to a new task.

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Task();

    $form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $task);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $tags = $form->get('tags')->getData();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        foreach ($tags as $tagName) {
            $tag = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Tag')->findOneBy(array('name' => $tagName));
            if (!$tag) {
                $newTag = new Tag();
                $newTag->setName($tagName);
                $em->persist($newTag);
            }
        }
        $em->persist($task);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('tasks_list');
    }
}
```

I got this error after submit:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class `AppBundle\Entity\Tag` could not be converted to string

I think that's because `Tag` entity is persisted before `Task` form is submitted.

How I can handle this part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't posted TaskType::class, I will guess that you have used this code snippet to get the tags:

```
$builder->add('tags', CollectionType::class, array(
   'entry_type' => TagType::class
));
```

You see, the way Symfony forms work, is they serialize the data that you have gotten from the user back to the entity. When you create a tags collection, what you are actually doing is serializing the tag names back to tag objects internaly. So this part of code:

```
$tags = $form->get('tags')->getData();
```

Actually gets the array of tag objects instead of just strings. That is why when you are looping through the array to check for existing tags:

```
foreach ($tags as $tagName) {}
```

$tagName is not actually the tag name. It is an object of class Tag. When you are trying to find a tag by tagName:

```
->findOneBy(array('name' => $tagName))
```

, what you are in fact doing is passing the doctrine repository a Tag object to query for the name. Now internaly it of course tries to convert it to string since you cannot compare an object to a string. This is why you are getting the error.

In order to achieve what you are trying to do, you will first have to:

```
->findOneBy(array('name' => $tagName->getName()))
```

(it would also be nice if you changed the naming of tagName at this point since it is not actually a name, its an object), then you if you find a tag in the database you should remove the object you had saved in this case in the tagName variable via $em->remove() and add the newly found tag to the task.

Comment: yes exactly , and in line ` $newTag->setName($tagName);` $tagName is trying to look for `__toString()` to convert object to string , which does not exists and hence ...good catch

Answer (score 1):

You should use Data Transformers. Reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

```
// src/AppBundle/Form/DataTransformer/TagToNameTransformer.php
namespace AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use AppBundle\Entity\Tag;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;

class TagToNameTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms an object (tag) to a string (name).
     *
     * @param  Tag|null $tag
     * @return string
     */
    public function transform($tag)
    {
        if (null === $tag) {
            return '';
        }

        return $tag->getName();
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a string (name) to an object (tag).
     *
     * @param  string $tagName
     * @return Tag|null
     * @throws TransformationFailedException if object (tag) is not found.
     */
    public function reverseTransform($tagName)
    {
        // empty tag name? It's optional, so that's ok
        if (empty($tagName)) {
            return;
        }

        $tag = $this->manager
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Tag')
            ->find($tagName)
        ;

        if (null === $tag) {
            // causes a validation error
            // this message is not shown to the user
            // see the invalid_message option
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                'An tag with name "%s" does not exist!',
                $tagName
            ));
        }

        return $tag;
    }
}
```

In `TagType` class add this code:

```
class TagType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ... your code

        $builder->get('name')
            ->addModelTransformer(new TagToNameTransformer($this->manager));
    }
}
```

Voila! If your tag already exists, it will be found and linked to your task.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's because you're redirecting to `tasks_list` that will show `Tag` you have persisted but you don't have a string representation for that object.

To avoid this error, introduce the following method into `Tag` entity

```
public function __toString()
{
  // This is only an example; you can insert 
  // here whatever you want to display
  // as tag's string representation

  return $this->name;
}
```

Comment: hello, no that's not a reason. I display tags as {{ tag.name }} in tasks_list page

Answer (score 0):

You have `cascade={"persist"}` on `$tasks` in `Tag` Entity; yet, you are persisting a `$task` after a `$tag`. Remove `cascade={"persist"}` on `$task` and try putting `cascade={"persist"}` on `$tags` in `Task` Entity and check if there is any difference.